# Iterating though each sequence of 3 items in list

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I receive a list from a server that contains 1007 items. The first 18 items are not important right now, but each 3 items starting from the 18 item needs to be together in a reversed way and divided by 1000

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,..,18,19,20,21,22,23...1007]
```

Start to loop from 18, take `18,19,20` and transform in `20,19,18` bound them together `201918` and `201918/1000` and return this value as `print(201918/1000)`

Next, do the same thing with `21,22,23` return `print(232221/1000)`

I wouldn't like to export modules, my application requests a lot of processing speed, because as you can see, there is a lot of items in that list, so as much as "real-time" those prints can be, better for me, and as much light as I can do it, I prefer.

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; see the [help].

Comment: The `itertool` module's documentation contains a recipe for this type of iteration.

Comment: The amount of work you are doing for each triple is negligible, and 1007 items is a relatively small list.

Comment: @chepner Would you know the specific function for it? I will be looking in the docs right now and try to find it, but if you don't mind telling me exactly what is the function, would be nice

Comment: I think it's called `chunk`; it's not in the module itself, but in the cookbook section near the end of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compress( numbers, offset=18, size=3, divisor=1000):
   numbers = numbers[ offset : ]
   op = []
   for i in range( 0, len( numbers ), size ):
     subnumbers = numbers[ i : i + size ]
     subnumbers = [ ::-1]
     subnumbers = map( str, subnumbers )
     val = float("".join(subnumbers ))
     op.append( val / divisor )
   retuen op
```

How does this work?

1. We slice the array by offset.
2. Reverse elements of given size
3. Convert to string
4. Convert to a single string and float
5. Divide the result and add to this to op list
6. return op list